# Tensorflow Data Adapter Error: ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

While running a sentdex tutorial script of a cryptocurrency RNN, link here

[YouTube Tutorial: Cryptocurrency-predicting RNN Model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWkpRdpOiPY&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfhTox0AjmQ6tvTgMBZBEXN&index=11),

but have encountered an error when attempting to train the model. My tensorflow version is 2.0.0 and I'm running python 3.6. When attempting to train the model I receive the following error:

```py
File "C:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 734, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

File "C:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 224, in fit
    distribution_strategy=strategy)

File "C:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 497, in _process_training_inputs
    adapter_cls = data_adapter.select_data_adapter(x, y)

File "C:\python36-64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 628, in select_data_adapter
    _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.float64'>"})
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Have you checked whether your training/testing data and training/testing labels are all numpy arrays? It might be that you're mixing numpy arrays with lists.

Answer (score 57):

You can avoid this error by converting your labels to arrays before calling `model.fit()`:

```
train_x = np.asarray(train_x)
train_y = np.asarray(train_y)
validation_x = np.asarray(validation_x)
validation_y = np.asarray(validation_y)
```

Answer (score 16):

If you encounter this problem while dealing with a **custom generator** inheriting from the `keras.utils.Sequence` class, you might have to make sure that you do not mix a `Keras` or a `tensorflow - Keras`-import.
This might especially happen when you have to switch to a previous `tensorflow` version for compatibility (like with `cuDNN`).

If you for example use this with a `tensorflow`-version > 2...

```py
from keras.utils import Sequence

class generatorClass(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        ...

    def __len__(self):
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return ...
```

... but you actually try to fit this generator in a `tensorflow`-version < 2, you have to make sure to import the `Sequence`-class from this version like:

```py
keras = tf.compat.v1.keras
Sequence = keras.utils.Sequence

class generatorClass(Sequence):

    ...
```

Comment: This was also my case, `keras` was imported both directly through statements like `from keras import layers` and via `import tensorflow.keras`. Ensure to stay consistent with the imports adding `tensorflow.` before each keras import or removing it.

Comment: life saver ..exact issue i was facing

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem. In my case it was a problem that I was using a `tf.keras.Sequential` model but a `keras` generator.

**Wrong:**

```py
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
gen = TimeseriesGenerator(...)
```

**Correct:**

```py
gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(...)
```

Comment: What's the difference here?

Comment: One uses plain keras, while the other uses tf.keras.

Answer (score 2):

This error occured when I updated tensorflow from 1.x to 2.x
It was solved after changing my import from

```
import keras
```

to

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I also experienced this problem when I passed my custom generator function directly to `model.fit()`, rather than creating an instance of it first.

I.e, given:

```
def batch_generator(...):
    ...
    yield(...)
```

I called `model.fit(batch_generator,...)`, rather than:

```
generator_instance = batch_generator(...)
model.fit(generator_instance, ...)
```

Answer (score -2):

may be it will help someone.
First check your data type if it is numpy array & possibly ur algo required a DF.

```
print(X.shape, X.dtype)
print(y.shape, y.dtype)
```

convert your numpy array into Pandas DF

```
train_x = pd.DataFrame(train_x)
train_y = pd.DataFrame(train_y)
```

Comment: I don’t see how Keras would accept pandas.DataFrame but not numpy.ndarray