# Encountering error for keras when implementing neural network with multiple outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, chess

I am implementing a chess AI in which the output is the position and the piece to be moved. However, when I follow the multi-output tutorial on [the keras API documentation](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/), It returns the error

```
Failed to find data adapter that can handle input:(<class 'list'> containing values of types {'(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {\'(<class \\\'list\\\'> containing values of types {\\\'(<class \\\\\\\'list\\\\\\\'> containing values of types {"<class \\\\\\\'int\\\\\\\'>"})\\\'})\'})'}), (<class 'dict'> containing {"<class 'str'>"} keys and {"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"} values)
```

Sorry if the copied section is too long, I just wanted to make sure that it could be easier to find what went wrong.

Reproducible section of code below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

board_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(8, 8, 12))


conv1= layers.Conv2D(10, 3, activation='relu')
conv2 = layers.Conv2D(10, 3, activation='relu')
pooling1 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding="valid", data_format=None,)
pooling2 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding="valid", data_format=None,)
flatten = keras.layers.Flatten(data_format=None)


x = conv1(board_inputs)
x = pooling1(x)
x = conv2(x)
x = flatten(x)
piece_output = layers.Dense(12,name = 'piece')(x)
alpha_output = layers.Dense(7,name = 'alpha')(x)
numbers_output = layers.Dense(7,name = 'number')(x)


model = keras.Model(inputs=board_inputs, outputs=[piece_output,alpha_output,numbers_output], name="chess_ai_v3")
model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.mse,
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    metrics=None,
)

keras.utils.plot_model(model, "multi_input_and_output_model.png", show_shapes=True)
history = model.fit(
    trans_data[:len(trans_data)],
    {"piece": pieces[:len(trans_data)], "alpha": alphas[:len(trans_data)],"number": numbers[:len(trans_data)]},
    epochs=2,
    batch_size=32,
)
# history = model.fit(trans_data[:len(trans_data)],batch_size=64, epochs=1000,verbosity = 2)
```

Update:
I am still having problems with the network, I tested each of the arrays of values set for the answer. They all function normally when executed individually, does anyone know of any problem that could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that your data are in a strange format. look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57874436/tensorflow-data-adapter-error-valueerror-failed-to-find-data-adapter-that-can)

I have no problem running this example

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models


board_inputs = layers.Input(shape=(8, 8, 12))
conv1= layers.Conv2D(10, 3, activation='relu')
conv2 = layers.Conv2D(10, 3, activation='relu')
pooling1 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding="valid", data_format=None,)
pooling2 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding="valid", data_format=None,)
flatten = layers.Flatten(data_format=None)


x = conv1(board_inputs)
x = pooling1(x)
x = conv2(x)
x = flatten(x)
piece_output = layers.Dense(12,name = 'piece')(x)
alpha_output = layers.Dense(7,name = 'alpha')(x)
numbers_output = layers.Dense(7,name = 'number')(x)


model = models.Model(inputs=board_inputs, outputs=[piece_output,alpha_output,numbers_output], name="chess_ai_v3")
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,8,8,12))
y = {"piece": np.random.uniform(0,1,(100,12)), 
     "alpha": np.random.uniform(0,1,(100,7)),
     "number": np.random.uniform(0,1,(100,7))}

history = model.fit(X,y, epochs=2, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: What types of data can support this neural network?

Comment: the most basic choice is numpy arrays in numerical format